# how can use category for post in to wordpress using c#

Tags: c#, wordpress

hi my program post to wordpress using c# but a i have a problem. when i post for first on with program is all one is ok but for second time in that i have posted second post that use one of first time category that before i have select. my codes in category section is same like this:

```
    string[] category;
    private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        if (index == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an category");
        }
        else
        {


    }
```

[see picture for information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpkLI.jpg)

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question to form a step by step explanation of what you expect this code to do and what actually happens?

Comment: Do you know if the problem at your end, e.g. selecting the category in your GUI, or at WordPress's end? Can you capture the XMLRPC post to see if it contains the correct category? Where did you get WordPressWrapper from - is that a library or something you've autogenerated from WordPress, or something else?

Comment: completed code about category added .i have a listbox that have multi category and i select tow or three category for post in wordpress. see the picture to know my problem

Comment: please help me.any body dosent way to help me

Comment: I'm not an expert so I probably can't help, but I still don't understand your problem. Your picture shows two categories "HDCam Camrip" and "DVDRip Camrip" but I'm not sure what's gone wrong: the second one shouldn't say CamRip? And the problem could be in one of three places: your code that assembles the category string to submit to WordPress, the code that assembles the XML-RPC request to WordPress or in WordPress itself. To start with you'll need to work out which and you're in the best position to debug that. Why are you assembling multi values into a string and then splitting it again?

Comment: Are you clearing `cat` before you start assembling it as a list of categories? I can't see that. Could that still have both values between submissions? (Not sure how that would explain all the behaviour though.)

Comment: my problem is for first one all one is ok and category with correct way posted in c# but in second time when i reset all item eg textboxs or combobox and checkboxs and ... i use this code for reset listbox items  listbox1.clear(); and then i want to put second post .here is my problem becuase i have select category that defrent form first post but in second post one category is same in first category like picture.actually use the first category post

Comment: OK. Can you debug and check the value of `cat` on the line where it gets split? I think the problem is that you are not clearing `cat` before the `for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)` loop and since I can't see the declaration here I assume that it's a class member or a global and so the value from the previous post is still in there at this point.

Comment: thanks Rup.my problem with your help resolved. thank you